# Asking for "Gas estimation failed" on BSC

Tags: 0x

I have problem on get quote always return "Gas estimation failed"

https://bsc.api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=0x3052c79b21bdd488a60da629ae3c2bb80599817c&sellToken=0xbb4CdB9CBd36B01bD1cBaEBF2De08d9173bc095c&slippagePercentage=0.13&takerAddress=0xbb8c0b3216b911e7ee9fd6d19f9c94d4f6d7dd46&includedSources=PancakeSwap_V2&sellAmount=100000000

What am I doing wrong? How do I do this?
Thank you.

Comment: I just clicked on the link and there is no error? Is this exact same call that you are doing?

Comment: on last week, I use this link reply response always estimate gas estimation failed, and I try after 3 day, link send response what  I need. I this this case is close and solved. Thank you